Configure data source in JBoss 7.4 with Microsoft SQL DB
I'm creating a data source in jboss with MS SQL DB. The required driver is loaded under the modules.
Testing the connection fails. Connectivity is fine between machines.
Connection url - jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost\dev;databaseName=dev_db
"WFLYJCA0040: failed to invoke operation: WFLYJCA0047: Connection is not valid"
Can someone please help on this?

Configured below connection string and it resolved the issue
jdbc:sqlserver://serverName;databaseName=dev_db;instanceName=sqldev;selectMethod=cursor;trustServerCertificate=true

Official documentation states:
The general form of the connection URL is

jdbc:sqlserver://[serverName[\instanceName][:portNumber]][;property=value[;property=value]]

where:

jdbc:sqlserver:// (Required) - Is known as the subprotocol and is constant.

serverName (Optional) - Is the address of the server to connect to. This address can be a DNS or IP address, or it can be localhost or 127.0.0.1 for the local computer. If not specified in the connection URL, the server name must be specified in the properties collection.

instanceName (Optional) - Is the instance to connect to on serverName. If not specified, a connection to the default instance is made.

portNumber (Optional) - Is the port to connect to on serverName. The default is 1433. If you're using the default port, you don't have to specify the port, nor the preceding : in the URL.

 Note

For optimal connection performance, you should set the portNumber when you connect to a named instance. This will avoid a round trip to the server to determine the port number. If both a portNumber and instanceName are used, the portNumber will take precedence and the instanceName will be ignored.

property (Optional) - Is one or more option connection properties. For more information, see Setting the connection properties. Any property from the list can be specified. Properties can only be delimited by using the semicolon (;), and they can't be duplicated.

You are defining localhost as a servername, still in question you state that "Connectivity looks fine between machines", this means either you have put wrong servername into connection string, either you messup something describing setup.
As final, putting the servername and port number for instance is suggested format (please use your configured port no):
jdbc:sqlserver://dbservername:1433;encrypt=true;databaseName=dev_db;integratedSecurity=true;

You have mentioned the connection string, but some apps require "Connection Properties" to be set instead of connection string. Please check that.
Finally please check the JBoss server.log for any driver specific issues.

if this will resolve your issue, consider to accept this answer

I have tried this - jdbc:sqlserver://dbservername:1433;encrypt=true;databaseName=dev_db;integratedSecurity=true;
But same error is being populated in logs and no driver exceptions
I have configured multiple db instances in same db. Is there any specific syntax to configure a instance?
